# How to load web page in browser internally from window service

Tags: c#

I have a windows service which have to load the web page. In web page there is a JavaScript function which will generate the Dynamic HTML.

Is there anyway to load web page in windows service as like on browser and can get the dynamic generated html.

It will be more helpful if you have other better way.

Thanks!!

I have tried some example WebClient and Html Agility Pack but cannot get the result as expected. It just return the HTML string of the webpage.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: You need an environment in which the downloaded JavaScript can actually be executed. So you'd need a headless browser, or some sort of package normally designed for automated GUI testing of web pages (e.g. I believe Selenium is one such thing, there may be others), and which can be automated from code. Alternatively, if this web page is from an application you control, consider instead creating an API which the windows service can call in order to get the equivalent data in a more friendly format, e.g. JSON